# How do I efficiently replace a set of substrings with other strings of the same length?

Tags: c, string, replace

I have a set of target strings and their replacements:

```
" </3"  "\xf0\x9f\x92\x94"
" <3 "  "\xf0\x9f\x92\x97"
" 8-D"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81"
" 8D "  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81"
" x-D"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81"
" xD "  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81"
" :')"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x82"
":'-)"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x82"
":-))"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x83"
" 8) "  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84"
" :) "  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84"
" :-)"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84"
" =) "  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84"
" =] "  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84"
" 0:)"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x87"
"0:-)"  "\xf0\x9f\x98\x87"
...
```

They are emoticons and the hex representation of corresponding emoji Unicode characters. I've padded with spaces so that both the emoticons and the replacement emoji strings are 4 bytes long.

I'm looking to replace emoticons with the corresponding emoji strings in an input file. What's the most efficient way of doing so?

- The input is already being scanned character by character for other purposes
- I can use C11 and POSIX libraries.

I'm thinking of two approaches:

- Piggyback the scanning, so that when a space, a `3`,`D`, `)`, `]` or any of the other characters which terminate an emoticon string arrives, check the last three characters to see if it's a valid emoticon, and then replace these with the corresponding emoji string.
- Compile a host of regexes (using `<regex.h>`), and apply all of them to the complete text, one after the other, and apply replacements.

The second method sounds horribly slow, but should code easy. Something like (pseudocode-ish, do forgive syntax errors):

```
struct emoticon_replacement {
   regex_t* regex;
   char *targ, *repl;
};
struct emoticon_replacement replacements[] = {
 {NULL, ...., ....},
 {NULL, ...., ....},
 {NULL, ...., ....},
....
};
// followed by regex initialization, taking advantage
// of sizeof(replacements)
// And again take advantage of sizeof(replacements) to loop
// over the regexes and replace occurences
```

The first method should be faster, if I could:

- match against all the the emoticon strings somehow ... like a DFA. A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) could come in handy.
- map the matched string with its replacement without coding an equivalent of C++'s `std::map`.

How can I efficiently implement either of these methods? What other options do I have?

---

Full disclosure:

This is part of a test.

Comment: Even for a test it still sounds a bit like premature optimization. I'd just go for the obvious way: (1) check if the char is one of those final characters, and (2) if so, scan the list of replacements and apply one if applicable.

Comment: @roeland True. Indeed, I'm thinking of using the regex way, because a) I haven't got to use regexes in C before, and I can combine a few equivalent emoticons in one regex. That said, I'd still like to know how an expert would approach the problem.

Comment: There's a `<regex>` header in C++11, but not in C. Make sure you tag your question as C++ if you're indeed talking about C++. The regex way is maybe more obvious, and probably fast enough.

Comment: @roeland There is a POSIX [`regex.h`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) which is meant to be used with C, though, and I have mentioned POSIX libraries in my post. No C++, however.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a chance of the data changing, you'll probably want to use some kind of map (e.g. a hashtable or a trie). Covering the theory of these seems unnecessary here, especially given that this option wasn't mentioned in the question... I just thought I'd mention some food for thought.

Otherwise, there's no chance of the data changing and I would highly recommend using a sorted lookup table, which is an optimised version of your first option so you can use binary searches instead of searching from the start of your array to the end. For example:

```
struct replacement {
    char original[4];
    char replacement[4];
};

int compare_replacement(void const *x, void const *y) {
    struct replacement const *fu = x, *ba = y;
    return memcmp(x->original, y->original, 4);
}

int main(void) {
    struct replacement table[] = {
        { .original = " </3" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x92\x94" },
        { .original = " <3 " , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x92\x97" },
        { .original = " 8-D" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81" },
        { .original = " 8D " , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81" },
        { .original = " x-D" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81" },
        { .original = " xD " , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x81" },
        { .original = " :')" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x82" },
        { .original = ":'-)" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x82" },
        { .original = ":-))" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x83" },
        { .original = " 8) " , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84" },
        { .original = " :) " , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84" },
        { .original = " :-)" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84" },
        { .original = " =) " , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84" },
        { .original = " =] " , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x84" },
        { .original = " 0:)" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x87" },
        { .original = "0:-)" , .replacement = "\xf0\x9f\x98\x87" }
    };

    qsort(table, sizeof table / sizeof *table, sizeof *table, compare_replacement);
}
```

Then you should be able to iterate from the start of the string to the end of the string, using `bsearch` to test each successive four bytes, like this for example:

```
void replace_emotes(char *str, struct replacement *rep, size_t rep_size) {
    while (*str) {
        struct replacement query = { 0 };
        strncpy(query.original, rep, sizeof query.original);

        struct replacement *response = bsearch(&query, rep, rep_size, sizeof *rep, compare_replacement);
        if (response) {
            strncpy(str, response->replacement, sizeof response->replacement);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you intend to support insertions, you need to work with `realloc` for a start... and either figure out where to insert to keep the array sorted before the insertion, or resort the array after each insertion. Either of these will work fine for modifications (insertions and removals) to small sets, but if you intend to support larger sets you'll probably want to use something like a trie or hashtable.